# Design DynamoDB Table for friendship

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking for the best way to design a DynamoDB table (supported by another MySQL database) to make a friendship system in my webapp.
I have those requirements: it should be easy and cost effective retrive all users friends (pagination whould be perfect) and an user could have "unlimited" friends.

I already use DynamoDB to keep track of an n-ary tree between all my users, so first method I've thoughts was to extend my previous work.

```
{
  "children": [
    1,
    1
  ],
  "id": 0,
  "parentId": -1
}
```

Just add a new list in my item:

```
{
  "children": [
    1,
    1
  ],
  "friends": [{"friend":"100","pending":"false","since":"2015-12-21T17:42:34Z","request":"2015-12-21T17:42:34Z"}],
  "id": 0,
  "parentId": -1
}
```

In this way to get all friends list is very easy and cost effective, but DynamoDB is limited to 400Kb per Item, so a friend element is more or less 70bytes, and so an user could have only 5k friends.

So I've thoughts this other method. Create a table only for friendship relations:

```
| User | Friend | Pending |         Since        |         Request       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1  |    2   |  false  | 2015-12-21T17:42:34Z | 2015-12-21T17:42:34Z  |
|   2  |    1   |  false  | 2015-12-21T17:42:34Z | 2015-12-21T17:42:34Z  |
```

So here an User could have "unlimited" friends, but when I need the friends list I must read all the table so I think this is not much cost effective, I can make this even with MySQL.

With both method there is still a problem, I must duplicate friendship informations. So I think that nor DynamoDB nor traditional SQL could help me to build a fast database. So may I wonder if there is another technology that I could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, modeling friendship the way you describe is a graph problem. And for representing graphs in databases, one would typically turn to a graph database.

While you can build a graph database on top of DynamoDb yourself, or by leveraging an open source implementation [JanusGraph](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend), Amazon now offers a managed graph database service called [Neptune](https://aws.amazon.com/neptune) (see features here: https://aws.amazon.com/neptune/features/)

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction, I'll study better Neptune and graph database in general

Answer (score 1):

We also have friending model in our application for millions of users and couple of them having more than 40k friends. I would suggest to build a bi-directional relationship entries e.g when A and B are friends then table should have two entries i.e. A -> Friend of B and B -> Friend of A. The friending start with sending request for friends (invitation) and then other side of the user has to either accept to invitation to be friend or reject (delete) invitation which means not want to be friend and in future the requestor also should not able to send the friend invite again to target user.
Let's start with two user A being requester and B being target using which whom A wants to be friend with.
Below are the flow of friendship:

1. Invitation from A to B
    A -> Invited B
    B <- Invited_By A
2. B accept the invitation from A then they both became friends
    A -> Friend B
    B <- Friend A
3. In case B decided not be friend of A and rejected the invitation
    A <- Rejected_By B
    B -> Rejected A
   At the given point in time, there should be only one relationship exist between two users and your table structure may looks like this

DynamoDb table structure:
Partition_Key : Requester_User_id
Sort_Key : Target_User_id

Other table's column which may be useful as per your need:
Relationship_Status : S (Invited, Invited_By, Friend, Reject, Rejected_By)
Request_Date : Date
Since_Date : Date

In this case you can get the list of friends of given user, list of users invitation sent, list of user who rejected my invitation and also list of users who still did not perform any action on my invitation.